# How to make value from a custom slider rounded to a certain pattern with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view like this:

[image]

So there are 2 `UITextField`s and a custom slider I made by following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7595-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider). As you can see the value of the `UITextField` is not rounded, what I want is to make the value rounded as these example cases (I hope you get the pattern):

- If the value is 12.000.000 - 12.149.000, rounded to 12.000.000
- If the value is 12.150.000 - 12.250.000, rounded to 12.250.000
- If the value is 12.251.000 - 12.350.000, rounded to 12.250.000
- If the value is 12.351.000 - 12.500.000, rounded to 12.500.000

Here's my slider action function:

```
func floorInteger(value: Double) -> Int{ // Since the slider value type is a double and starts from 1.25 to 35.0, i had to make this function to adjust to my currency
        return Int(floor(value * 1000000))
    }

@IBAction func sliderAction(_ sender: Any) {
        minPrice = "\(floorInteger(value: rangeSlider.lowerValue))" // set the min value
        maxPrice = "\(floorInteger(value: rangeSlider.upperValue))" // set the max value
        updateHargaFields() // Updating the text fields each time i slide the slider
    }
```

How can i achieve this? I'm still new to iOS programming so i still have little experience. If you need more code feel free to ask. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want any values less than millions rounded according to your custom logic? But it looks like you’re multiplying your value by 1_000_000? (Underscore acts as an ignored thousands separator in Swift, FYI, so you can use that to make it more readable.)

You could use `.truncatingRemainder` to find the remainder after division of a Double. Then alter that remainder according to your pattern and add it back to your floor’ed value. And finally multiply that by 1m. But there may be some weirdness in the Double's significant figures.

I think it's best to get your Double to an Int right away, then you can use the modulus `%` operator, and you'll be sure that when you multiply by 1m, you won't get something weird like Rp 12.250.001.

```
func sliderToCurrency(value: Double) -> Int{ 
    let amount: Int = Int(value * 1_000_000)
    let remainder = amount % 1_000_000
    let base = amount - remainder
    var rounded = 0

    if remainder < 150_000 {
        rounded = base
    } else if remainder <= 350_000 {
        rounded = base + 250_000
    } else if remainder <= 500_000 {
        rounded = base + 500_000
    } // else if etc...

    return rounded
}
```